# Ida Pro: how do I iterate over all typedefs in python

Tags: ida, idapython

I see how to iterate over all structs, unions, enums, functions.  But I cannot find a way to iterate over all typedefs.

Comment: Use a combination of `range(idaapi.get_ordinal_qty())` and `idaapi.get_numbered_type`, pass the results as parameters to `tinfo_t.deserialize`, then filter the results with `tinfo_t.is_typeref`... Or if you're using the `minsc` library, you'd use `database.types.iterate(typedef=True)` or `database.types.iterate(typeref=True)`.

Comment: Thanks @AliRizvi-Santiago.  Your answer is enough to go on.